# How to store the user id in session mvc c#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i am doing one project on Selvel system. i am new in MVC. l done some tasks in project.completing one task.i find one error. i want to display on dashboard that according to lead and task the data show.so i want to store user-id in session for leaddecripton and teak Status

Comment: thanks a lot.for help

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Session["userId"] = your_user_id;
//to clear the session value
Session["userId"]=null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you can also opt between `Cookies` or `TempData` or `ViewData` or `ViewBag`. They are other options for persisting data. For sessions, I recommend you this official link.

[Using Session State in your application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Hope this helps.